# Replacing all but one type of character in a string: Python

Tags: python, string, char

```
 choice = "lillian"
 firstpick = "l"

 for n in choice:
    if n != firstpick:
       inverse = n
       if inverse in choice:
           print(choice.replace(inverse,'-'))
```

The desired output of this code would have been "l-ll---" but it was "l-ll-an"
"l-ll-an"
"lilli-n"
"lillia-"

Sorry about this, I'm not the best at code but I'd appreciate a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

```
choice = "lillian"
firstpick = "l"
''.join([c if c==firstpick else '-' for c in choice])
```

Comment: @user17805349 If it solved your problem, please mark this answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so you'll need to store the result of the replacement. Try this:

```
choice = "lillian"
firstpick = "l"

for letter in choice:
    if letter != firstpick:
       choice = choice.replace(letter, '-')

print(choice)
```

Comment: Note that if `choice` is very long, this method will slow down considerably compared to @OfirY's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can replace list comprehension with generator expression in @OfirY's answer like so:

```
choice = 'Lillian'
firstpick = 'l'
''.join(c if c == firstpick else '-' for c in choice)
```